# Call PHP constant by name vs number

Tags: php

I need to print the constant name instead of the number:

```
class Type
{

    const UNKNOWN = 0;
    const PERSON = 1;
}
```

I have a function: `entity->getType()`
Which return a number in this case 0 or 1.

How can I use PHP to convert the const UNKNOWN or PERSON to text without doing this:

```
$entity_types = [
            0 => 'UNKNOWN',
            1 => 'PERSON'];

printf('Type: %s' . PHP_EOL, $entity_types[$entity->getType()]);
```

But by calling:

`Type::$entity->getType()`?

Comment: Just curious: why would you want that? You should probably be able to get that from the reflection API, but that's a strange need.

Comment: yes you can like Jeto said: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php

Comment: I have a class with ~20 different constant values, would like to improve readability

Comment: I currently dont have access to Class Type code, is in an external library. Thanks

Comment: If you need to be able to read your constant values, just give your constants readable values. "unknown" and "person" are better values than 0 and 1 unless you are SEVERELY constrained on space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there's no real solution to your problem. Simple example, why this couldn't work in PHP:

```
const VAR1 = 1;
const VAR2 = 1;
```

That is a total valid usage of class constants, but as there are multiple uses of the value `1`, there isn't a mapping of `1` to any name.

There might be a way to use the reflection api to return the first constant with a matching value, but doing this in production isn't recommend, as this isn't very fast (and as I said before, also unsafe if you later change your code)

If you want to improve the readability if const values, you should think about using string's as values for the constants and not numbers.